# How can i set PDB (Pod Disruption Budget) for CFK Kafka connect resource

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using confluent cloud and then have Connect cluster using CFK

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kubernetes-examples/tree/master/hybrid/ccloud-integration

Its all working fine but i am not sure how can i set PDB as i have 8 replicas and i use karpenetr to scale nodes.  I have to setup PDB to make sure atleast 7 replicas run at all times

```
---
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Connect
metadata:
  name: connect
  namespace: confluent
spec:
  replicas: 1
  image:
    application: confluentinc/cp-server-connect:7.4.0
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.6.0
  tls:
    autoGeneratedCerts: true
  mountedSecrets:
    - secretRef: kafka-client-config-secure
  dependencies:
    kafka:
      bootstrapEndpoint: <cloudKafka_url>:9092
      authentication:
        type: plain
        jaasConfig:
          secretRef: cloud-plain
      tls:
        enabled: true
        ignoreTrustStoreConfig: true 
    schemaRegistry:
      url: https://<cloudSR_url>
      authentication:
        type: basic
        basic:
          secretRef: cloud-sr-access
---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like this;

```
---
apiVersion: platform.confluent.io/v1beta1
kind: Connect
metadata:
  labels:
    app: connect
  name: connect
  namespace: confluent
spec:
  replicas: 7
  image:
    application: confluentinc/cp-server-connect:7.4.0
    init: confluentinc/confluent-init-container:2.6.0
  tls:
    autoGeneratedCerts: true
  mountedSecrets:
    - secretRef: kafka-client-config-secure
  dependencies:
    kafka:
      bootstrapEndpoint: <cloudKafka_url>:9092
      authentication:
        type: plain
        jaasConfig:
          secretRef: cloud-plain
      tls:
        enabled: true
        ignoreTrustStoreConfig: true 
    schemaRegistry:
      url: https://<cloudSR_url>
      authentication:
        type: basic
        basic:
          secretRef: cloud-sr-access
---
```

```
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: connect-pdb
  namespace: confluent
spec:
  minAvailable: 7
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: connect
```